# aspnet5 dnu restore fails due to windows path length limitation

Tags: asp.net-core

I am testing thew new aspnet5 framework and when running "dnu restore" on Windows (works fine on OSX) I get the error:

```
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

I have searched online and this is apparently due to a Windows path length limitation. The workaround/hack that some people are attempting are using environmental variables to make the path shorter however this doesn't really seem like a great solution as it would need to be performed manually on every developers machine who works on the project and on the server during the build.

My question is what solutions are people implementing here that fixes the problem without having to configure manual settings on every computer that works on the project?

Comment: Are you hitting this issue? https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/300

Answer (score 0):

We know there are some limitation in terms of path length and we have them tracked but for now the only solution is to move your project closer to the drive's root.